# Python - Remove list(s) from list of lists (Similar functionality to .pop() )

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

.pop() has the capacity to not only remove an element of a list but also return that element.

I am looking for a similar function that can remove and return a whole list that could exist in the middle of another list.

E.g is there a function that will remove `[4,5,6]` from the above list `a`, and return it.

The reason for the question is that I'm sorting a list through `itemgetter` and there's a collision between the headings row (string) and the rest of the data (`datetime`).  As such, I'm looking to effectively pop the list which represents the headings, do a sort, then insert it back in.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The nested lists are just values in the outer list. Just use `.pop()` on that outer list:

```
inner_list = a.pop(1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> a.pop(1)
[4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You could just use a slice to remove the first row from consideration if a header row is in the way:

```
result = rows[:1] + sorted(rows[1:], key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: @SteveJessop: ah, yes, I prefer lists being cleanly set with spacing. :-P That was me cleaning up the OP formatting without spaces, and accidentally including those 2 extra lines in the paste here.

Comment: Nice one-liner.  Thanks

Comment: To accomplish the endgoal, just use the last line of Martijn's answer