# Remove a list from a list of lists Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of lists:

```
[[0.0,3.3, 4.9, 7.5], [4, 6, 90, 21, 21.1], [3, 43, 99, 909, 2.11, 76, 76.9, 1000]]
```

I want to remove a sublist from the list if that sublist contains an element outside a given range.

For example; range = 3, 15

So, if a sublist contains, -69, -17, 0, 1, 2, 15.1, 246.99, i.e any element that is outside that range, I want that sublist removed.

The output that should be returned is a list of lists where all the sublists only contain values within that range:

```
[[6, 5, 7, 13, 12], [4, 6, 10], [9, 9, 4, 5, 11], [4, 4]]
```

I am aware that there are similar questions here such as:

[Removing sublists from a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209786/removing-sublists-from-a-list-of-lists)

[Python - Remove list(s) from list of lists (Similar functionality to .pop() )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21860605/python-remove-lists-from-list-of-lists-similar-functionality-to-pop)

I cannot get these solutions to work.

My goal is to not remove duplicates of lists: there are a lot of questions about that but that is not my goal.

My code:

```
max_value = 15
min_value = 3

for sublist in my_list:
  for item in sublist:
    if(item < min_value):
        my_list.pop(sublist)
    if(item > max_value):
        my_list.pop(sublist)
print(my_list)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Which line gives that error? Could you post a traceback?

Comment: it may be `my_list.pop(item)`

Comment: Line 7, my_list.pop(sublist). After the first IF statement

Comment: It seems that your example is inconsistent.  You output does not tie out with your input.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use list comprehension. Here is a sample input and output. The idea is simple: For each sublist just check for the `min` and `max` if they fall outside the desired limits.

```
list_1 = [[0.0,3.3, 4.9, 7.5], [4, 6, 9, 11, 12.1], [3, 43, 99, 909, 2.11, 76, 76.9, 1000], ]

left = 3
right = 15

list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if (min(i)>=left and max(i)<=right)]
print (list_2)
# [[4, 6, 9, 11, 12.1]]
```

Comment: Clever with the min and max.  `[*filter(lambda x: min(x) >= 3 and max(x) <= 15, list_1)]`

Comment: @piRSquared: Thanks for the comment. :) Your comment is definitely more concise and less verbose

Answer (score 4):

Your error comes from using the `.pop()` method, which expects an integer index as its argument, when you really mean `.remove()`.  However, even after correcting this to `.remove()` you may also experience errors from trying to remove items from a list while iterating over it.  A cleaner approach is a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[0.0,3.3, 4.9, 7.5], [4, 6, 90, 21, 21.1], [3, 43, 99, 909, 2.11, 76, 76.9, 1000]]
min_value = 3
max_value = 100

my_list[:] = [sublist for sublist in my_list if all(min_value <= x <= max_value for x in sublist)]
```

Comment: Is `all` really needed here?

Comment: @Bazingaa. Is anything really necessary? But seriously, `all` is probably the best way to do it.

Comment: @Bazingaa  yes. The fate of a sublist depends on conformance by all of its members. Or otherwise stated, if any member does not conform, the whole sublist is out.

Comment: @jez: What I was thinking is that you are using two for loops in your code when you can get done with one. But as I said, nice approach +1 as I learned the use case of `all`

Comment: @Bazingaa One way or another you have to iterate over the whole of each sublist. With `min` and `max` you're doing that too (twice in fact) but likely faster because of the way they're implemented.

Comment: @jez: Roger that :)

Answer (score 1):

a list comprehension

```
new_list = [sublist for sublist in list if not any(el in range(a, b) for el in sublist)]
```

Comment: What do you expect `not any(el in sublist)` to do?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: nothing. just pressed enter at the wrong time

Comment: this only works for integers (which is probably ok), and you may have meant `range(a, b+1)`